# manage memory which was not dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a c++ programmer coming from C# background and still have some confusions about memory management in c++

I have a class with three functions

1st returns a pointer to a local variable

2nd returns a pointer to a list of pointers

3rd returns a pointer to a list of lists of pointers

consider this code:

**AugmentedActivePastConjugator.h**

```
class AugmentedActivePastConjugator {


    public:

    AugmentedActivePastVerb* createVerb(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root, int pronounIndex, int formulaNo);

    vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>* createVerbList(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root, int formulaNo);

    vector<vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>*>* createAllVerbList(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root) ;

};
```

**AugmentedActivePastConjugator.cpp**

```
AugmentedActivePastVerb* AugmentedActivePastConjugator::createVerb(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root, int pronounIndex, int formulaNo) {
    string lastDpa = PastConjugationDataContainer.getLastDpa(pronounIndex);
    string connectedPronoun = PastConjugationDataContainer.getConnectedPronoun(pronounIndex);
    AugmentedActivePastVerb verb (root,lastDpa,connectedPronoun,formulaNo);
    return &verb ;
}

vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>* AugmentedActivePastConjugator::createVerbList(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root, int formulaNo) {
    vector<AugmentedPastVerb *> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        AugmentedActivePastVerb* verb = createVerb(root, i, formulaNo);
        result.push_back(verb);
    }

    return &result;

}

vector<vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>*>* AugmentedActivePastConjugator::createAllVerbList(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root) {
    vector<vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>*> result;
    vector<AugmentationFormula*>::iterator  begin = root->getAugmentationList().begin();
    vector<AugmentationFormula*>::iterator  end = root->getAugmentationList().end();
    while (begin !=end) {
        AugmentationFormula* formula =  *begin;
        vector<AugmentedActivePastVerb*>* formulaVerbList = createVerbList(root, formula->getFormulaNo());
        result.push_back(formulaVerbList);
    }
    return &result;
}
```

if I want to create a list of verbs returned by this class, for example

```
// general variable
list<AugmentedActivePastVerb *> verbslist;
AugmentedActivePastConjugator conjugator;

void createverbslist()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
        AugmentedActivePastVerb* verbs = conjugator.createVerb(someroot, pIndex, fNo);
        verbslist.push_back(verb)
    }

}
```

what should I do after I have finished using *verbslist*, should I delete all the pointers inside it or will it free them automatically

I have read an article that says:

> don't free memory which was not dynamically allocated

so if I shouldn't free it, what happens to those pointers inside *verbslist*

Comment: `AugmentedActivePastVerb verb; return &verb;"` is wrong and leads to UB. Don't return the address of a local variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Don't return pointers if you are managing there memory. The memory should be managed by an object (container for collections smart pointer for a single object). You return pointers only when you absolutely have too and they should not indicate ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AugmentedActivePastVerb verb (root,lastDpa,connectedPronoun,formulaNo);
return &verb ;
```

Never ever do this. `verb` is allocated on the stack and gets destroyed as soon as the method call is removed from the stack. And voila, your applications points to a variable that's no longer in its place.